# android: new project create duplicate android-support-v4.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I am aware of how to fix this error. I am trying to find a solution that prevents eclipse from creating these duplicate .jar files as it is really becoming a nuisance now.

I was previously using ADT22.xx until a few days ago when google rolled out adt23.xx and my whole IDE decided to blow up.

I have since downloaded Eclipse Luna and installed new software to get the ADT onto my upgraded IDE. This seemed to work fine, but I did notice my buildpath refers to android.jar in the old adt tools .... (still seems to work and if it ain't broken don't try to fix it).

However, everytime I create a new Android project in Lunar I get this annoying error saying that it finds a duplicate android-support-v4.jar file. One is in filepathtoproject/libs and the other is in C../../appcompat_v7/libs.

I know that I can just copy the one from appcompat and put into my app's libs folder, but is there a way to get it to import the one from appcompat automatically?